# Implementing Voice calls using mumblesharp

Tags: c#, voip, mumble-web

I need to implement Voice calls using Mumblesharp, can anyone share a code snippet, I can use?.

I have gone through the demo apps in github for mumblesharp but they do not implement actual voice calls. This is urgently required.

I have also installed the mumble server and client on my system and cloned the mumble sharp repository to check the implementation but no luck yet

Comment: "This is urgently required." Urgency is never relevant to Stack Overflow. If you asked a specific question rather than just for "share a code snippet" you'd be much more likely to get an answer - the more urgent the request is *for you*, the more effort I suggest you put into asking a good, specific, well-researched question... as that's more likely to get you an answer quickly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.